# Multipart Download from S3 using Pre-signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download

I have an application that receives a pre-signed URL to download an object from S3. Currently the application is implemented to download the whole object (multi-gigabyte size) in one go. If there is any interruption, it has to request for a new pre-signed URL (if expired) and restart the download from the start.

Is there any way for an external application that has a valid pre-signed URL to download the object in parts? (assuming URL is valid).
The application is using curl get API to download the file.

I did find this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/s3-optimizing-performance-best-practices/use-byte-range-fetches.html

However, how would the above work with the pre-signed URL?

Comment: The client can use a normal presigned link with byte range requests to resume a download and/or download separate chunks of the object at once.